# Is there a function for checking if a time interval overlaps in a single column and sort by group in R

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have a large dataset and I'm trying to find where time intervals overlap by group. To complicate things further I'm hoping that the code could be integrated with the 'dplyr' group_by function so the overlapping times don't get confused with other ids.

I've tried using the overlapping function "int_overlaps(int1, int2)" from "lubridate", but this doesn't work for one column. Any other overlapping functions appear to not work with time intervals.

```
library(lubridate)

id <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
start <-as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-27 09:30:00","2017-06-27 15:30:00",
                     "2017-06-27 14:30:00","2017-06-28 09:30:00","2017-06-28 15:00:00"),tz= "UTC")
end <-as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-27 10:30:00","2017-06-27 17:30:00",
                   "2017-06-27 18:30:00","2017-06-28 10:30:00","2017-06-28 16:00:00"),tz= "UTC")
inter1<- interval(start,end,tz="UTC")

df <- data.frame(id,inter1)

overlap <- c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)

new_df<-data.frame(id,inter1,overlap)
```

Comment: Can you check the example. `df <- data.frame(id,inter1)
Error in data.frame(id, inter1) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 5`

Comment: Could you addthe definition  for `id`? And, to be clear, is `overlap` your desired result?

Comment: Apologies the first two lines of the code were missing, the objective is to identify overlapping time points and sorting this by group (i.e. ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample data doesn't have any overlapping periods.  The following change was made:

```
start <-as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-27 09:30:00","2017-06-27 15:30:00",
                     "2017-06-27 14:30:00","2017-06-28 09:30:00","2017-06-28 15:00:00"), tz= "UTC")
```

Using `lead` will return `NA` if it is the last record in a group

```
library(dplyr)

new_df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(int_start(inter1), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(overlap2 = lead(int_start(inter1)) < int_end(inter1))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id inter1                                           overlap overlap2
  <dbl> <Interval>                                       <lgl>   <lgl>   
1     1 2017-06-27 09:30:00 UTC--2017-06-27 10:30:00 UTC FALSE   FALSE   
2     1 2017-06-27 14:30:00 UTC--2017-06-28 18:30:00 UTC TRUE    TRUE    
3     1 2017-06-27 15:30:00 UTC--2017-06-27 17:30:00 UTC TRUE    NA      
4     2 2017-06-28 09:30:00 UTC--2017-06-28 10:30:00 UTC FALSE   FALSE   
5     2 2017-06-28 15:00:00 UTC--2017-06-28 16:00:00 UTC FALSE   NA
```

If needing to compare each row to all rows within the group

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(int_start(inter1), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(overlap2 = map_int(inter1, ~ sum(int_overlaps(.x, inter1))) > 1)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id inter1                                           overlap overlap2
  <dbl> <Interval>                                       <lgl>   <lgl>   
1     1 2017-06-27 09:30:00 UTC--2017-06-27 10:30:00 UTC FALSE   FALSE   
2     1 2017-06-27 14:30:00 UTC--2017-06-28 18:30:00 UTC TRUE    TRUE    
3     1 2017-06-27 15:30:00 UTC--2017-06-27 17:30:00 UTC TRUE    TRUE    
4     2 2017-06-28 09:30:00 UTC--2017-06-28 10:30:00 UTC FALSE   FALSE   
5     2 2017-06-28 15:00:00 UTC--2017-06-28 16:00:00 UTC FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: This does not give the same answer as the question shows and it only checks intervals in adjacent rows rather than all rows in the same id.

Answer (score 1):

**1) sqldf** Assuming you only want to overlap the times and not the dates, replace `inter1` with `start`, `end` as well as the starting and ending times, `time1` and `time2`, giving `new_df1`.  Then do a self join on `id` and the
overlap condition grouping by `rowid`.  `overlap` is TRUE if the count of matching rows exceeds 1 (since overlapping itself does not count).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(sqldf)

new_df1 <- new_df %>% 
  mutate(
    start = int_start(inter1),
    end = int_end(inter1),
    time1 = sub(".* ", "", start),
    time2 = sub(".* ", "", end),
    inter1 = NULL
  )

sqldf("select a.id, a.start, a.end, count(*) > 1 as overlap
  from new_df1 a 
  join new_df1 b on a.id = b.id and
    (a.time1 between b.time1 and b.time2 or b.time1 between a.time1 and a.time2)
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  id               start                 end overlap
1  1 2017-06-27 05:30:00 2017-06-27 06:30:00   FALSE
2  1 2017-06-27 11:30:00 2017-06-27 13:30:00    TRUE
3  1 2017-06-28 10:30:00 2017-06-28 14:30:00    TRUE
4  2 2017-06-28 05:30:00 2017-06-28 06:30:00   FALSE
5  2 2017-06-28 11:00:00 2017-06-28 12:00:00   FALSE
```

**2)** This forms the full ni x ni join for each id i and then filters it down and groups it as a second and third step whereas (1) does these all at once so depending on the SQL optimizations applied by the database software (1) might be much more efficient.  Anyways, this joins on `id` and then filters on the overlap condition and finally does the counting. `new_df1` is from (1).

```
new_df1 %>%
  mutate(rowid = 1:n()) %>%
  inner_join(new_df1, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  filter((time1 >= time1.y & time1 <= time2.y) | 
    (time1.y >= time1 & time1.y <= time2)) %>%
  count(rowid, id, start, end) %>%
  mutate(overlap = n > 1) %>%
  select(id, start, end, overlap)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  rowid start               end                 overlap
  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>  
1     1 2017-06-27 09:30:00 2017-06-27 10:30:00 FALSE  
2     2 2017-06-27 15:30:00 2017-06-27 17:30:00 TRUE   
3     3 2017-06-28 14:30:00 2017-06-28 18:30:00 TRUE   
4     4 2017-06-28 09:30:00 2017-06-28 10:30:00 FALSE  
5     5 2017-06-28 15:00:00 2017-06-28 16:00:00 FALSE
```

### Note

The poster changed the question after it was already answered but in any case we used this as the input.

```
new_df <-
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), inter1 = new("Interval", 
    .Data = c(3600, 7200, 14400, 3600, 3600), start = structure(c(1498555800, 
    1498577400, 1498660200, 1498642200, 1498662000), tzone = "UTC", 
    class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), tzone = "UTC"), overlap = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question, as it doesn't identify the overlap?

Comment: Then please fix the question since this gives the same result as the one shown as expected in the question.

Comment: There was an error when I made my first edit, and it added the wrong dates for row 3, this is the data you're using, and as you'll see there's no overlap in times between start and end of row 2 and start and end of row 3 so I'm unsure why it says true?

Comment: The times in rows 2 and 3 overlap. The question states that you want to check the overlap of the times, not the dates and times and furthermore the result shown in the question is consistent with times only.